# how to find a var whether is string or number(but avoid exponential) in php

Tags: php, numbers, exponential, isnumeric

I am using is_numeric to find a var whether its string or number but I want to consider `exp` also a string but as per php doc is_numeric considers `exp` as number.

I want to check all number formats like int, floats and double but not octal, hexadecimal and exponential(consider them as string).

is there any function for this?

```
$value = 4e2137383789;
if (is_string($value)) {
    echo "yes it is a string";
} else {
    echo "no it is not a string";
}
```

above code consider `$value` as `numeric` but I want to consider it like `string`.

Comment: I think only regex because is_float match scientific notation of number

Comment: I also thought to go with regex , anyway thank you dude